# Run clang-format from rootful container on bind-mounted host dir without changing ownership

Tags: docker, chown, ownership

I want clang-format run from within a container on a bind mounted host directory to keep the ownership of modified files.

I have a simple Dockerfile which I'm running with `podman`. I bind mount the container when running to the host directory like this `sudo podman run -v $PWD:/app clang-format`.

I am running `podman` with sudo, making it rootful. This is required at my company. The `clang-format` binary is only available to me on the container.

The `clang-format` run from the container currently changes ownership to the docker root user.

```
FROM my-base-image-with-clang-format

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT find . -regex ".*\.\(cpp\|h\)" -exec clang-format -i {} \;
```